# ASP.NET Eager-loading a tree hierarchy of references

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, dbcontext, eager-loading

With my current database model I'm trying to load the complete table set with every reference and sub-references an entry may have. That is so the view can display the query in a tree like hierarchy. Where each entry lies under its parent.

Say in the following fashion

- Real Estate

  - Apartment
- Vehicle

  - Land

    - Urban
    - Terrain
  - Air
  - Water

The problem stems from that the entries have to be loaded with there parents and parents parents .etc depending on the depth of the tree. I suspect that it have to do with that an entry may have cyclic references.

Can this be achieved with my current db model or do I need to change it?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MySolution.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
       [Key]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public string ImageSource { get; set; }

       public Category Parent { get; set;  }


       public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That can work yes but it's not very self desciptive design, why not make it with proper names. EG have one class called Vehicle that has the fieds Land Air and Water then make classes for each of those with fields describing themselves

Comment: But if I have to change or add a new category I can't do it through a form on the website, I have to update the database with new models. This is more to be used as a filter where only "posts" of a certain selected category is displayed.

Comment: Oh they're for categories, sorry, missed that. Yeah that does look fine then, however I personally might call it sub/super categories rather than children/parent but that's not really relevant

Comment: I think that's a better name for them. But I think I have to use another entry which is level of the category, so if a parent category has level n the children have n+1. Seems redundant but it will eliminate the reference cycles and sort them into an array ranging from the roots to the depth of the tree. Any comment regarding that fix is much appreciated.